# Leaflet not working loading on Firefox

Tags: leaflet

I have leaflet map on the page which is working fine with Chrome, IE but not loading at all on Firefox. Not able to detect what the issue is. I get this error message:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening? I am using leaflet CDN to get the JS and CSS.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try to clear the browser cache

Comment: already did that multiple times but still the same issue

Comment: Maybe you can show us your code

Comment: Apparently that error is typical from some Salesforce stuff. It would be interesting to know which libraries and frameworks you're using. And provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)